# How to Compare dates with Xpath in android

Tags: java, android, xml, xpath

I want to try parse xml with XPath in Android Application. 
My XML file looks like this.

```
<expenses>
    <entry type="fixed">
        <amount>200</amount>
        <recurring>true</recurring>
        <category>Home/Rent</category>
        <payee>Ahmet Necati</payee>
        <account>1</account>
        <startDate>2013-01-01</startDate>
        <endDate>2013-01-01</endDate>
    </entry>
    <entry type="variable">
        <amount>150</amount>
        <category>Departmental</category>
        <payee>Ahmet Necati</payee>
        <recurring>true</recurring>
        <startDate>2013-01-01</startDate>
        <endDate>2013-01-01</endDate>
        <account>1</account>
    </entry>
</expenses>
```

and I want to try parse xml with xPath like that

```
String expression = "/expenses/entry[xs:date(endDate) < xs:date('2013-10-10')]";
NodeList widgetNode = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate(expression, document,
        XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

But I couldnt deal with it. It returns 0 node.

Edit: I want to get all nodes "endDate" less than spesific date for example: I want to get nodes which end Date less than "2013-10-10"

Comment: Clarify your question please. What's your problem?

Comment: I want to get all nodes "endDate" less than spesific date for example: I want to get nodes which end Date less than "2013-10-10"

Answer (score 1):

The "XML schema constructor functions" are part of XPath 2.0, but Android only supports XPath 1.0: http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html

One solution is to register your own function to do the conversion (see `XPathFunctionResolver`). Another is to look into libraries that support XPath 2.0.